# How do I make timer wait until done?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, updatepanel

I have an ASP.NET website where I have to show some data on a `Gridview`, I need this data to be shown as fast as possible, so I decided to create a timer inside an Update panel and then Refresh the grid over and over, however I see that my timer is not waiting until it was done in order to `Tick` again, it's executing itself over and over, which is giving me performance issues on the database, how can I tell my timer "hey stop until this process is done, then continue".

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="400" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" EnableViewState="False">
            </asp:Timer>
            <asp:GridView ID="gv_stats" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" GridLines="Vertical" Width="562px" OnRowDataBound="gv_stats_RowDataBound" ShowFooter="True" EnableViewState="False" >
                   <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                        <Columns>
                        </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I tried this:

```
     private bool is_refreshing = false;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        }
    }

    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer1.Enabled = false; 
        if(is_refreshing == false)
        BindGrid();
        Timer1.Enabled = true; 



    }

   public void BindGrid()
        {

            is_refreshing = true;
            grd.datasource = con.executedt;
            grd.databind();
            is_refreshing = false;
         }
```

Comment: Please add the code-behind from `Timer1_Tick` to the question, also add the things you have already tried to make this work.

Comment: Ok, Anchit, I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refresh the grid, you can set a private boolean variable indicating the that the grid is refreshing and before the execution of code that refreshes the grid, you can check this variable.

**EDIT -** Try using a session variable instead of a private variable. **See updated example.**

Example -

```
// code change starts
private bool _isGridRefreshing
{
   get
   {
      var flag = HttpContext.Current.Session["IsGridSession"];
      if(flag != null)
      {
         return (bool)flag;
      }

      return false;
   }
   set
   {
      HttpContext.Current.Session["IsGridSession"] = value;
   }
}
// code change ends

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(_isGridRefreshing == false)
   {
       RefreshGrid();
   }
}

private void RefreshGrid()
{
   _isGridRefreshing = true;

   //code to refresh the grid.
}
```

Note - I haven't tested the code, but it should give a fair idea of what needs to be done.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, it's still doing it.

Comment: @user3044096, please add all the necessary information to the question, including what all you have tried but didn't work.

Comment: Thanks, i ended up doing that, but I did it with view state instead, thanks!(I guess we both forgot for a minute that asp.net is stateless)